# Struts2 Ajax validation not working

Tags: ajax, struts2

Parent package is not defined: json-default - [unknown location]

```
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:493)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)


Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)


Caused by: Parent package is not defined: json-default - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildPackageContext(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:674)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:523)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:295)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:264)
```

Comment: Downvoted because there is no actual question. We need a question, some context, what you've tried, etc. if we're to try and answer this.

Answer (score 2):

@lokesh this is **not** the right way to ask here on StackOverflow. An error only is not enough, consider posting your code, or additional details, etc. or your questions will be downvoted, closed, deleted.

BTW

> Caused by: Parent package is not defined: json-default - [unknown location]

To use a package extending `json-default`, you need to include the [struts2-json-plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html).

Download it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-json-plugin).